# I cannot render an animation with CUDA

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I cannot render a animation with CUDA. This is my script and the commandline order:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.user_preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type = 'CUDA' bpy.context.user_preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.devices[1].use = False bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
bpy.context.scene.render.tile_x = 256 bpy.context.scene.render.tile_y = 256
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

This is the command:

```
blender -b mainfile.blend -E CYCLES -t -a //file -P script.py
```

*Sometimes says "error there is no //file " and sometimes begin the render but using the cpu..*

HELP

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` option is to specify how many threads are used for rendering, this should be followed by a number but the `-a` you have following it will give you an error.

The main issue you have with your command is that blender [executes the arguments in the order they are given](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-order). Following it through means that blender starts in background mode, loads mainfile.blend, sets the engine to cycles, incorrectly sets the threads, renders an animation, opens the file `//file` then runs the script `script.py`.

What should work for you is -

```
blender -b mainfile.blend -E CYCLES -P script.py
```

If you are adding `//file` to specify the output file for the render, then you need to put `-o` in front of it (and add a file extension) and if it is a folder then also add a trailing slash `-o //test_renders/`.

You may also want to remove the render line from your script and use `-f <frame number>`. Note that using `-f` to render a specific frame from the command line will save the image to file so you don't need the render step in your script.

```
blender -b mainfile.blend -E CYCLES -P script.py -o //file.jpg -f 1
```

Comment: Thanks sambler its work ´s!!!!!! for an animation i should put -a ?  and for a part of the animation ? thanks !!!

Comment: You can find all the options in [blenders manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) or with `blender --help` -- `-a` renders the entire animation. `-f 2` will render just frame 2. `-s 10 -e 15` will render frames 10 to 15 of an animation. `-j 5` will only render every fifth frame in an animation.